# Copy table structure and data into 2D array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Here I have a MySQL database and I need to retrieve many rows.

I need the data to stack up in one array:

```
$query_sel_node  = "SELECT * FROM $table_name";                 
$result_data = mysql_query($query_sel_node);

$data_rec = array("data" => array(), "data_h" => array(), "file" => array(), "ptr" => array(), "name" => array());
while($data_fetched = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_data))
                {   
                    array_push($data_rec["data_h"], $data_fetched['data_h']);
                    array_push($data_rec["data"], $data_fetched['data']);
                    array_push($data_rec["file"], $data_fetched['m_file_thumb']);
                    array_push($data_rec["ptr"], $data_fetched['m_pointer']);
                    array_push($data_rec["name"], $data_fetched['m_name']);
                }
```

now, i've added alot of columns to my table , which means i would need to array_push() for every single column i made.

is there a easier way that i can do this with fewer lines of code?

what i'm looking for is this:

i have a mysql table with column {m_data, m_name, m_file}
and i have several rows of data

now i need to get them into array

my array will use the column names an the key,
then i'll store my row data into each key

Comment: What does your query look like?

Comment: updated my question, check again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get all of the column names from the desired table:

```
SELECT
    COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
    table_name = '$table_name'
```

Build the array (`$table`) with the column names and assign an empty array to each one (for the data):

```
$columns_query = mysql_query($the_above_query);
$table = array();
while ($column = mysql_fetch_row($columns_query))
    $table[$column[0]] = array();
```

Fetch the data for each column and insert it into the `$table` array:

```
foreach (array_keys($table) as $column)
{
    $query_sel_node  = "SELECT $column FROM $table_name";                 
    $result_data = mysql_query($query_sel_node);

    while ($data = mysql_fetch_row($result_data))
        $table[$column][] = $data[0];
}
```

Now, `$table` will contain the exact structure and data that the table `$table_name` does.

Comment: what if i want the entire row? does your method still work? if so, how do i create the $data_rec array to let my query go in

Comment: put it this way, how do i create a $data_rec array that has all the columns of my table? without typing it myself....

Comment: So you want to get the entire table as an associative array?

Comment: but not array_push($data_rec,$data_fetched); since it will be adding arrays not stacking the elements in them

Comment: So you don't want to use your `$data_rec` array structure? (A parent array with the columns having their own arrays).

Comment: i was using that array simply because i need a container to put my mysql data; i was looking for a better solution

Comment: Could you post an example (in your question) of what you want the result to look like?

Comment: what i mean is not that i dont want the array, what i want is the array having the same structure of my table columns

Comment: Ah, so you want your exact table structure and data represented by an array.

Comment: Use [`mysql_fetch_field()`](http://php.net/mysql-fetch-field) instead of querying the informaton schema table.

Comment: @Kolink Is one better than the other?

Comment: mysql_fetch_field() works on the query itself, whereas this answer has you run a second query just to get the information that's already there. mysql_fetch_field() is much better.

Comment: I had a better idea - see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Even better than querying information schema or using mysql_fetch_field, try this:

```
$query_sel_node  = "SELECT * FROM $table_name";
$result_data = mysql_query($query_sel_node);
$data_rec = array();
while($data_fetched = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_data)) {
    foreach($data_fetched as $k=>$v) {
        $data_rec[$k][] = $v;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is definitely more compact and only queries the database once, instead of (number of columns + 1).